# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, upon click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a totally new to Javascript/jQuery and I am creating two objects named `mapMTK` and `keyAndDatatye` as given in below:

HTML

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="templ">Module Template Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="formModuleName" name="DSname" class="input-large">
            <option>TitleImageModule</option>
            <option>SearchBoxModule</option>
            <option>CategoryLinksModule</option>
            <option>BannerSlidesModule</option>
            <option>StoreNavigationModule</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="clickme">click me</button>
```

Javascript

```
function keyAndDatatype(key, datatype) {
    this.key = key;
    this.datatype = datatype;
}

var mapMTK = {};

mapMTK["TitleImageModule"] = [
    new keyAndDatatype("title", "ImageObj")
];

mapMTK["SearchBoxModule"] = [
    new keyAndDatatype("searchBox", "LinkObj")
];

mapMTK["CategoryLinksModule"] = [
    new keyAndDatatype("subStores", "LinkObj"),
    new keyAndDatatype("title", "TextObj")
];

mapMTK["StoreNavigationModule"] = [
    new keyAndDatatype("anchorTags", "ImageLinkObj"),
    new keyAndDatatype("titleImage", "ImageObj"),
    new keyAndDatatype("title", "TextObj")
];

var inputModuleName;

$('#formModuleName').change(function () {
    inputModuleName = this.value;
});

$('#clickme').click(function () {
    alert(mapMTK[inputModuleName].length);
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/hmb2v/)

I'm using the `mapMTK[inputModuleName].length` with a jQuery `click` event it gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

While using same `mapMTK[inputModuleName].length` in Javascript works fine.

```
<missing example>
```

How I can use it in my jQuery code?

Comment: 1. if JS tells you something is undefined - it is. No reason to not trust JS 2. JS objects don't have a `.length` property

Comment: well, where is `input` defined? In fact, where's this `jQuery` code you're going on about?

Comment: Back to the basic JS tutorials, I would say, with all the best intentions.

Comment: [Crayon Violent](http://stackoverflow.com/users/184595/crayon-violent) Pls see this here it works fine but not in my code [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CyXCg/)

Comment: `inputModuleName` is `undefined` until you `change` the drop-down.

Comment: @Xotic750 thanxs for the clew it works fine after changing the dropdown but how i can remove this error ... One option is default define the inputModuleName any other good way u can tell..

Comment: Read the `value` of the drop-down at the time of `click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
var inputModuleName;

$('#clickme').click(function () {
    alert(mapMTK[inputModuleName].length);
});
```

now it's obvious, that `inputModuleName` is undefined and thus will be `mapMTK[inputModuleName]`.

as long as this function

```
$('#formModuleName').change(function () {
    inputModuleName = this.value;
});
```

has not been executed, `inputModuleName` and `mapMTK[inputModuleName]` are undefind.

Answer (score 0):

Change your:

```
var inputModuleName;

$('#formModuleName').change(function () {
    inputModuleName = this.value;
});

$('#clickme').click(function () {
    alert(mapMTK[inputModuleName].length);
});
```

to

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {
    var inputModuleName = $('#formModuleName').val();
    alert(mapMTK[inputModuleName].length);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to find the length of an object, which won't work unless its an array object:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};  //undefined
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // 3

alert(obj.length);
alert(arr.length);
```

Comment: Its an Object with arrays as properties an `mapMTK[inputModuleName].length` tries to get the length of the array assigned to the property. So you're misleading the OP.

Comment: In your fiddle, only the first one doesn't work, because you don't set inputModuleName until the onChange event is fired.

Comment: Try this to make sure that you always capture the selected option. http://jsfiddle.net/hmb2v/4/